# How to prevent normal cursor behavior when pressing keys in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, pug

I have the following code

```
 textarea#main-text-area(
        rows="1"
        ref="textArea"
        maxlength="4096"
        v-model="message"
        :placeholder="placeholder"
        @keyup="onTextAreaKeyUp"  
        @change="onChangeMessage"
        :class="{ 'vars-error': varsError }"
        v-click-outside="onTextAreaBlur"
      )
```

and i listen for the keyup event. I need the cursor not to move when I press up or down.

I tried to do the following but it didn't work for me as the cursor moved anyway

```
onTextAreaKeyUp(e) {
      if (e.key === 'ArrowDown' || e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preventDefault` on the `keydown` event instead of `keyup`.

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.key === 'ArrowDown' || e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
    e.preventDefault()
  }
})
```

```html
<textarea>Hello, World! Hello, World! Hello, World! Hello, World! </textarea>
```